# Find hsql database data and view data?

Tags: eclipse, hsqldb

Been playing around with Hsqldb, was able to create db, insert data then view the data. I use HsqlProperties class, set property to a folder on my desktop for the database - this folder now contains script, properties, log and lck file.

My question is, where is or which file is the data actually stored and how can I view the data I have inserted into the db like the db explorer of visual studio (i'm using eclipse IDE)?

Answer (score 0):

I use the HSQL database manager to see the database schema in tree form, though you have to write a query to view the data.  It does have a context menu for making select and other statements.  It also has a "recent queries" and other useful features. To run HSQL Database Manager:

```
 @java -classpath hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing
```

Here is a sample connection url to use once HSQL Database Manager is open:
     url: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/

from the [docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html) the data is in these files:
.script  - the definition of tables and other objects, plus the data for non-cached tables. 
.data - data for cached tables and the backup file is a compressed backup of the last known consistent state of the data file.

A table is cached when you create it with the cached keyword

```
create cached table ms.timeSlot (
    firstname varchar(5)
);
```

Comment: Thanks matt. I am having problems run HSQL Database Manager. Firstly, I cannot find hsqldb.jar. Is there any other way I can load it?

Comment: Just be sure hsqldb.jar is in the same folder as the script that will start DatabaseManagerSwing.  Either that or provide the full path to hsqldb.jar.  Look in the lib folder of the download zip.